# Syntax to Specify both ServiceBehavior and EndpointBehavior?

Tags: wcf, web-services, web-config, servicebehavior, endpointbehavior

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731303.aspx, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789007.aspx, examples are given which specify ServiceBehavior, but is there a way to specify an endpointBehavior in the behaviorConfiguration as well?  Something like

```
  <service name="ServiceName1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior1;EndpointBehavior1"> 
...
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior1">
...
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpointBehavior1">
...
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly question, The endpoint element of the web.config also has its own behaviorConfiguration attribute.

```
    <endpoint
      behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior1" ...
```